# How can I use jQuery hotkeys to load link?

Tags: jquery, hyperlink, keyboard, hotkeys

I am sorry if I have missed it somewhere, but I have searched and searched for this and cannot find the code to make this work. I anticipate it is very simple, but not being familiar with javascript I have not been able to implement it.

I am working on using the jquery hotkeys plugin https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys to assign individual letter keys (for example, i, g, etc.) to links, so that the website can be navigated with the keyboard or mouse. I do not want to do anything fancy, simply have the key load a page in the browser, same as if you clicked on any typical link.

All I have been able to do is get an alert to display with this code:

```
$(document).bind('keydown', 'i', function() {
    alert('You found the hotkey!');
});
```

But anything I have tried to get a link to load when the i is pressed has not worked. Can anyone advise me on what code to use? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is simple solution :

```
$(document).keydown(e)
{
   if( e.keyCode == 13 )//enter for example
   {
       window.location.href ='http://...';
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me to use the following code (so that I could stay within the jquery hotkeys plugin):  $(document).bind('keydown', 'i', function() {  window.location.href ='http://...';  });

Answer (score 0):

To bind a `keydown()` to the body:

```
$(window).keydown(
    function(k){
        if (k.which == 49){
            alert("You pressed '1'!");
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/P5cs2/3/).

You could restrict this to non-input elements using the following approach:

```
$(window).keydown(
    function(k){
        var notTheseOnes = ['textarea','input'];
        var target = k.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
        if (k.which == 49 && $.inArray(target,notTheseOnes) < 0){
            alert("You pressed the '1'!");
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/P5cs2/2/).

Comment: Doesn't work for me. `$(window)` however does: http://jsfiddle.net/WDNvn/ (binding to document works, too)

Comment: Hnh...interesting! I tested my demos in Chromium (Ubuntu 11.04), but not Firefox: indeed, Firefox does require the selector to be the `$(window)` or the `$(document)`. ...edited; and thank you..!